# Number of relations on a set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

What is the number of relations on a $n$ element set that are antisymmetric and not symmetric?
  I have soved this question using the fact that 'antisymmetric and not symmetric' means asymmetric...
 So answer will be $$3^{\left(\frac{n^2-n}{2}\right)}$$ Is it correct?

Comment: What does "asymmetric" mean in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No -- $3^{(n^2-n)/2}$ counts the relations that are *antisymmetric* and *irreflexive* (it also counts the relations that are *antisymmetric* and *reflexive*, but that is unlikely to be what you had in mind). Instead:

First let's count the *antisymmetric* relations. For each of the $\binom n2$ unordered pairs or elements we can either have $aRb$ or $bRa$ or neither, giving 3 choices. Additionally each of the $n$ elements can either be related to itself or not.

One of these relations is *symmetric* exactly if all of the $\binom n2$ answers are "neither" (and then it is immaterial which elements are related to themselves). So you need to subtract those cases.